# The correct way to use the GNU linker

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I am trying to use a couple of libraries, libglfw3-dev and libglew-dev, on an ubuntu environment but have been unable to get the linker to perform its intended purpose. I would normally use a makefile but for the purpose of debugging I have just used g++ on the CLI.

`g++ -I-Iinclude -I/usr/include/GL -I/usr/include/GLFW  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`

I understand that I need to specify the libraries themselves with the -l flag but get an error of the form

`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibglfw`

Here is some information about the locations of the packages (omitting irrelevancies)

```
root@Jake-Faptop:/usr/include/GLFW# dpkg -L libglfw3-dev
/usr/include/GLFW/glfw3.h
/usr/include/GLFW/glfw3native.h
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglfw.so
```

```
root@Jake-Faptop:/usr/include/GLFW# dpkg -L libglew-dev
/usr/include/GL/glew.h
/usr/include/GL/glxew.h
/usr/include/GL/wglew.h
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so
```

The names of the shared libraries have been a matter of great confusion to me as it turns out they are named `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so.2.1.0` and `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglfw.so.3.3`

---EDIT---

In light of the advice given to omit prefixes and suffixes on the library names I am still getting linker errors on the following input

`g++ -Iinclude -I/usr/include/GL -I/usr/include/GLFW -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lGLEW -lglfw src/main.cpp -o build/main`

->

```
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x3b): undefined reference to glfwTerminate'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x54): undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x63): undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x72): undefined reference to glfwWindowHint'
```

Confused.com...

Comment: Remove `lib` at the beginning of the names

Comment: should I omit the version number and the .so suffix too?

Comment: Yes, you only pass the library name without `lib` and without suffix (`.so`, `a`, ...) and without version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `lib` at the beginning of the names. E.g. the library's name is

```
libGLEW.so.2.1.0
```

Link it with

```
-lGLEW
```

This will link to `libxGLEW.so` which usually is a symlink to a versioned library like `libGLEW.so.2.1.0`.

> -llibrary
>
> -l library
>
> Search the library named library when linking. (The second alternative with the library as a separate argument is only for POSIX compliance and is not recommended.)
>
> The -l option is passed directly to the linker by GCC. Refer to your linker documentation for exact details. The general description below applies to the GNU linker.
>
> The linker searches a standard list of directories for the library. The directories searched include several standard system directories plus any that you specify with -L.
>
> Static libraries are archives of object files, **and have file names like liblibrary.a**. Some targets also support shared libraries, **which typically have names like liblibrary.so**. If both static and shared libraries are found, the linker gives preference to linking with the shared library unless the -static option is used.
>
> **It makes a difference where in the command you write this option; the linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the order they are specified. Thus, ‘foo.o -lz bar.o’ searches library ‘z’ after file foo.o but before bar.o. If bar.o refers to functions in ‘z’, those functions may not be loaded.**

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html

Comment: @JakeO'Neill Try `g++ src/main.cpp -o build/main -Iinclude -I/usr/include/GL -I/usr/include/GLFW -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lGLEW -lglfw` The last paragraph in my answers says: _"It makes a difference where in the command you write this option; the linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the order they are specified. Thus, ‘foo.o -lz bar.o’ searches library ‘z’ after file foo.o but before bar.o. If bar.o refers to functions in ‘z’, those functions may not be loaded."_